# No national characters in mail subject using imaplib, email in Python to read gmail inbox

Tags: python, email, imaplib, charset

Windows. Python 3.9.
As a value of mail subject I get other characters instead of Polish characters - I get:

Odpowied�� automatyczna: "Re: Program licz��cy ceny i sprzeda�� w allegro dla EAN��w"

instead of:

Odpowiedź automatyczna: "Re: Program liczący ceny i sprzedaż w allegro dla EANów"
[image: Pycharm variable view]

How to make it correct? Should I apply some codepage information somewhere?

I notice all out dictionary values are string except for the subject which is of type Header.

```
import imaplib, email
mail = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')
mail.login('user', 'pwd')
mail.select('inbox')
data = mail.search(None, 'ALL')
_, data = mail.fetch(str(7), '(RFC822)')
message = email.message_from_bytes(data[0][1])
out = {
    'from': message['from'],
    'subject': message['subject'],
    'to': message['Delivered-To'],
    'datetime': message['Date'],
    'cc': message['Cc']
}
```

Comment: Are you on Windows?  Most likely, you actually are receiving the correct characters, but your console doesn't have the right code page to display them.'

Comment: @TimRoberts I am. The values show up in Pycharm

Comment: You can you provide the raw value of the header (with View Source or similar?)  It hsould like Subject: =?utf-8?Q?…?=

Answer (score 0):

if understand correctly you need to decode bytes.
try something like

```
from email.header import decode_header

subject, encoding = decode_header(message["subject"])[0]
if isinstance(subject, bytes):
    subject = subject.decode(encoding)
```